# Does SVN have an equivalent for "hg clone" in Mercurial or "git clone" in Git?

Tags: svn, mercurial

I have a URL for a Subversion repository and on the command line on Ubuntu I want to just download a copy of the repository as you would do in Mercurial by typing:

```
hg clone http://svn.somerepository.com/somerepository/trunk/docs/
```

1. How do you "clone" a repository in SVN?
2. Also, **I just want to get everything below the `docs` folder** - I don't want to start in the trunk - how would you do something like this:

   svn clone http://svn.somerepository.com/somerepository/trunk**/docs/**

Comment: mercurial can "clone" svn repos with hgsubversion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to perform what in SVN-land is called a "check out."

```
svn co http://svn.somerepository.com/somerepository/trunk/docs/
```

Note the main difference between SVN and distributed systems like Mercurial or Git is that SVN's "check out" command downloads only a copy of the most recent version of each file, whereas with `hg clone` you will actually end up with a local copy of the repository's entire history as well.  This has some implications for the way in which you work.  For example, you need to have a network connection to the server in order to retrieve logs, perform diffs, etc.

Answer (score 6):

If you just need to grab the current version, `svn checkout` is all you need.

If you want a complete copy of the repository, including all previous versions, you can use [`svnsync`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svnsync). It can copy a complete repository and incrementally download new commits. I don't think it can be restricted to subdirectories though.

Answer (score 4):

1. <s>You can't clone the repository without having admin access to it (i.e. the ability to do `svnadmin` commands).</s>
2. You can certainly check out the subtree with `svn co http://....../docs`

Comment: You *can* clone a repository without admin access using svnsync, but this almost certainly isn't what the OP wants since such a clone is useless for making commits back to the real repository. This is the fundamental difference between distributed (git, hg, ...) and centralized (svn, cvs, ...).

Comment: @bendin Thanks...I was unfamiliar with `svnsync` and this usage of `clone`.

Answer (score 2):

```
svn co svn://www.example.com/path/to/repository/...
```

In which "co" is short for "checkout".

Comment: @calmh I think the question was coming from more of a workflow standpoint than a "how do I get a copy of the entire repository history."

Comment: @Nick Given the accepted answer, probably. I was fooled by the "copy of the repository" talk.